# need help installing bathroom solid surface countertop that does not sit flush on vanity

Tags: vanity

I bought a new bathroom countertop that is a solid surface.  It's called a "stonetek solid surface".  The bottom surface of the vanity top has all sorts of groves in it.  So I don't know how to attach the top to the vanity because there is nothing to screw to, or put adhesive on.  Any help you can provide would be really appreciated!
Thanks, Jeannie

Comment: Any chance of a picture of the underside? The web seems to be devoid of anything but pictures of the top side.

Answer (score 1):

In my limited experience, the top is commonly adhered with either silicone caulk, or hot glue, neither of which care much about grooves (they will fill them where they happen to meet the glueline.)

Typically make some sort of witness marks as you where you want the top, remove it, glue or caulk on the top of the vanity, set the top in place following the witness marks, let it cool or cure depending which type of adhesive was used.